# iPhone layouts without using auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, autolayout

i am new to iOS Development and working on an application. i want to handle layout for iPhone5 and iPhone6 without using auto layout.

The layout i designed

[image]

The layout look like on iPhone6 simulator

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you don't want to use auto-layout you will have to adjust the horizontal position of the "green" control in relation to the width of its parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple XIBs/Storyboards for the layouts on different devices and check if the device is an iPhone 5 or iPhone 6 when you load the XIB/Storyboard.

This would be really cumbersome task, laying out same UI for two different devices, you may want to consider using Auto Layout at some point of time

Answer (score 0):

Add outlets for all components to the related class and do all the calculation there.